# list of keyvaluepair to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, silverlight, list

I'm working on a Silverlight application. Since SL doesn't support arraylist, I'm making do with Arrays and List of objects.
I want to convert a list of keyvaluepair to an array.
But when I do the following:

```
private KeyValuePair<String, int>[] array1;
List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> list1 = methodCall.Result();
array1 = list1.ToArray();
```

I have debugged and confirmed that list1's results are not empty as a result of the method call. However, array1 is empty even after the conversion. What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** here's the full code for code behind.

```
private KeyValuePair<String, int>[] array1;
private KeyValuePair<string, int>[] getlocalUniversities() 
{
    ASASService.ASASServiceClient client1 = new ASASService.ASASServiceClient();
    client1.getLocalUniversitiesCompleted += new EventHandler<ASASService.getLocalUniversitiesCompletedEventArgs>(client_getLocalUniversitiesCompleted);
    client1.getLocalUniversitiesAsync();
    return array1;
}
void client_getLocalUniversitiesCompleted(object sender, ASASService.getLocalUniversitiesCompletedEventArgs ex) 
{
    if (ex.Error == null && ex.Result != null)
    {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list1 = ex.Result;
            array1 = list1.ToArray();
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

//

```
THE ASASService method getLocalUniversities() returns a List<KeyValuePair<String, int>>.
From there, I see that it has 1(expected) result consisting of <"NUS", 50>.
However, when I get it here as ex.Result, ex.Result contains 1 result consisting of <null, 0>.
```

Comment: You didn't by chance happen to declare a local variable `array1` and set the result to that instead?

Comment: @JeffMercado's comment makes sense in the light that the code you posted isn't complete- array1 is clearly a field, but the other 2 lines look like they belong in a method.  There is something else going on here- what is it?

Comment: "Making do" with `List<T>`?  I'd ditch `ArrayList` for `List<T>` 99% of the time.

Comment: If you need Key/Value pair why not go with a     Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: What type does Result() return? The only thing I can think of is that some kind of implicit cast is happening, because List<T>.ToArray(T) return an IEnumerable<T>, whereas your array1 is not a generic, but a type of KeyValuePair<String, int>[].

Answer (score 2):

I think that you probably made a mistake when debugging. Assuming your Result() method is working fine, the code you listed should have worked. I ran this as a test and it worked fine.

```
KeyValuePair<string, int>[] array1;
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("one", 1));
list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("two", 2));
list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("three", 3));
array1 = list1.ToArray();
```

Comment: yes, it should have worked fine, except that it isn't direct - the data source was via a service passed over as ASASService.getLocalUniversitiesCompletedEventArgs ex

Comment: A bit different problem. Your service call, getLocalUniversities() returns array1 but array1 will not yet have a meaningful result in it at the point of return. Service calls in Silverlight are asynchronous so when you return array1, the completed event is most likely still executing. If you examine ex.Result and see <null, 0> I suspect that there is something wrong in your service.